# advice to make my below Pig code simple

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Here is my code and I do two group all operations and my code works. My purpose is to generate all student unique user count with their total scores, student located in CA unique user count. Wondering if good advice to make my code simple to use only one group operation, or any constructive ideas to make code simple, for example using only one FOREACH operation? Thanks.

```
student_all = group student all;
student_all_summary = FOREACH student_all GENERATE COUNT_STAR(student) as uu_count, SUM(student.mathScore) as count1,SUM(student.verbScore) as count2;

student_CA = filter student by LID==1;
student_CA_all = group student_CA all;
student_CA_all_summary = FOREACH student_CA_all GENERATE COUNT_STAR(student_CA);
```

Sample input (student ID, location ID, mathScore, verbScore),

```
1 1 10  20
2 1 20  30
3 1 30  40
4 2 30  50
5 2 30  50
6 3 30  50
```

Sample output (unique user, unique user in CA, sum of mathScore of all students, sum of verb Score of all students),

```
7 3 150 240
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: i don't really know pig so can't give you an exact answer, but conceptually i think you want `GROUP student BY (student, LID)`, to aggregate your data down to a more managable size, but still preserving the granularity you need then, then your 'FOREACH` aggregations will be much faster

Comment: @maxymoo, you mean group by location (LID) only? Or by location + student ID?

Comment: group by both, then you'll have a table of size #locations * #students. then optionally filter by location or sum the whole thing up to get your two types of aggregation

Comment: @maxymoo, thanks, but student ID is unique, what is the purpose of group by student ID + location ID? BTW, if you could write your code down, it will be much clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for this.

```
data = load '/tmp/temp.csv' USING PigStorage(' ') as (sid:int,lid:int, ms:int, vs:int);

gdata = group data all;

result = foreach gdata {
        student_CA = filter data by lid == 1; 
        student_CA_sum = SUM( student_CA.sid ) ;
        student_CA_count = COUNT( student_CA.sid ) ;
        mathScore = SUM(data.ms);
        verbScore = SUM(data.vs);
        GENERATE student_CA_sum as student_CA_sum, student_CA_count as student_CA_count, mathScore  as mathScore, verbScore as verbScore;
 };
```

Output is:

```
grunt> dump result
    (6,3,150,240)
grunt> describe result
    result: {student_CA_sum: long,student_CA_count: long,mathScore: long,verbScore: long}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahendra, why do you COUNT( student_CA.sid ), other than COUNT( student_CA) ;

Comment: Hi Mahendra, thanks for all the help and mark your reply as answered. Have a good weekend. :)

Comment: @LinMa both `COUNT(student_CA.sid)` and `COUNT( student_CA)` will result the same, I used it mistakenly due to copy paste.

Comment: Thanks Mahendra, for COUNT(student_CA.sid) and COUNT( student_CA), their logical meaning are the same?

Comment: A minor diffrence is present between `COUNT(student_CA.sid)` and `COUNT( student_CA)`. `COUNT( student_CA)` will count the total number of tuples (you can consider tuples as rows) in student_CA bag while `COUNT(student_CA.sid)` will count the number of non-null `sid` in student_CA bag. So suppose you have 5 entry in a bag in which only 4 sid present and in 5th tupple sid is null then `COUNT( student_CA)` will give you 5 but `COUNT(student_CA.sid)` will give you 4.

Answer (score 1):

first load the file(student)in hadoop file system. The perform the below action.

```
split student into student_CA if locationId == 1, student_Other if locationId != 1;

student_CA_all = group student_CA all;

student_CA_all_summary = FOREACH student_CA_all GENERATE COUNT_STAR(student_CA) as uu_count,COUNT_STAR(student_CA)as locationCACount, SUM(student_CA.mathScore) as mScoreCount,SUM(student_CA.verbScore) as vScoreCount;

student_Other_all = group student_Other all;

student_Other_all_summary = FOREACH student_Other_all GENERATE COUNT_STAR(student_Other) as uu_count,0 as locationOtherCount:long, SUM(student_Other.mathScore) as mScoreCount,SUM(student_Other.verbScore) as vScoreCount;

student_CAandOther_all_summary = UNION student_CA_all_summary, student_Other_all_summary;

student_summary_all = group student_CAandOther_all_summary all;

student_summary = foreach student_summary_all generate SUM(student_CAandOther_all_summary.uu_count) as studentIdCount, SUM(student_CAandOther_all_summary.locationCACount) as locationCount, SUM(student_CAandOther_all_summary.mScoreCount) as mathScoreCount , SUM(student_CAandOther_all_summary.vScoreCount) as verbScoreCount;
```

output:

```
dump student_summary;
(6,3,150,240)
```

Hope this helps :)

*While solving your problem, I also encountered an issue with PIG. I assume it is because of improper exception handling done in UNION command. Actually, it can hang you command line prompt, if you execute that command, without proper error message. If you want I can share you the snippet for that.*

Answer (score 1):

The answer accepted has an logical error.

Try to have the below input file

```
1 1 10  20
2 1 20  30
3 1 30  40
4 2 30  50
5 2 30  50
6 3 30  50
7 1 10  10
```

The output will be

```
(13,4,160,250)
```

The output should be

```
(7,4.170,260)
```

I have modified the script to work correct.

```
data = load '/tmp/temp.csv' USING PigStorage(' ') as (sid:int,lid:int, ms:int, vs:int);

gdata = group data all;

result = foreach gdata {
    student_CA_sum = COUNT( data.sid ) ;
    student_CA = filter data by lid == 1;
    student_CA_count = COUNT( student_CA.sid ) ;
    mathScore = SUM(data.ms);
    verbScore = SUM(data.vs);
    GENERATE student_CA_sum as student_CA_sum, student_CA_count as student_CA_count, mathScore  as mathScore, verbScore as verbScore;
```

};

Output

```
(7,4,160,250)
```